# Which part of a cow does UK "frying steak" come from?

Tags: beef, steak, cut-of-meat, butchering

UK supermarkets often sell cuts of meat with ambiguous names that don't resemble the cuts on a butchery diagram:

[image]

Where would I find frying steak on that?

Answer (score 1):

According to [this site](http://www.simplybeefandlamb.co.uk/cuts-beef/fryingminute-steak) the frying steak is cut from the thick flank.